# Загрузка css-файла в кэш

Tags: html, css

Сделал сайт с помощью bootstrap. На компьютере все работает идеально. Но если изменить что-то в css и залить на хостинг, то изменения появляются лишь после очистки кэша. Как избавиться от этой проблемы?

Comment: Я советую при изменении css. Менять в шапке название файла css. Допустим был style.css, ставите style.css?v=2.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри настройки хостинга , там есть кэширования данных , может включено на несколько дней или мес. - смени!